# Can I add non-trees to terrain.terrainData.treeInstances on Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, c#, tree, prefabs

I need to create a brush in which there will be stones, poles, bushes and other elements of the environment. I bought a [Prefab Brush](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/prefab-brush-21321). Whether it is possible to add the objects that I draw on the Prefab Brush scene to terrainData.treeInstances, as regular trees add?

Is it possible to use a not prefab tree as an object for the TreeInstance class?

Comment: Isn't the example video in the asset showing how to add stones and trees with the same brush? Or is your question to add an object with the brush that is not a prefab?

Comment: @Zibelas my question is can i add a prefab brush to terrainData.treeInstances?

Comment: @Zibelas on video a prefab is created in the scene and objects  added to prefab . And I need these objects to be in terrainData, and not  on scene

Comment: I'm not sure if something like this is what you need just the other way around https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-placing-trees-with-scripts-on-terrain.462885/

Comment: @Zibelas  Can I add non-trees to terrain.terrainData.treeInstances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically add any game object to the tree brush in the terrain object how ever the objects might not be rendered as you like since they will follow the billboard rules of trees.